# Group by Day in Django

Tags: django, group-by, django-queryset

Alguém ai tem um exemplo de "bat-pronto" de um agrupamento por data? Tentei tudo isso aqui...

```
Subscription.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date(created_at)'}).values('day').annotate(available=Count('created_at'))

from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
Subscription.objects.extra({'date':"date(created_at)"}).values('date').annotate(count=Count('id'))



from django.db import connection
from django.db.models import Count

select = {'day': connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day', 'created_at')}
Subscription.objects.extra(select=select).values('day').annotate(number=Count('id'))
```

Mas nenhum retornou o que quero:

```
2016-01-22, 10
2016-01-21, 5
2016-01-15, 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Django aggregation, group by day

```
import datetime
import itertools
qs = Subscription.objects.values('created_at').values('created_at')
grouped = itertools.groupby(qs, lambda d: d.get('created_at').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
[(day, len(list(this_day))) for day, this_day in grouped]
```

Return

```
[('2016-01-24', 7),
 ('2016-01-22', 13),
 ('2016-01-21', 5),
 ('2016-01-15', 9),
 ('2016-01-14', 1),
 ('2016-01-09', 20)]
```

http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/02/24/django-aggregation-group-by-day.html

Comment: @Orion Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note que essa resposta faz o agrupamento na aplicação (python) em vez de no BD (SQL), e por isso pode ser bem menos eficiente no caso de um conjunto de dados grande (pois todas as linhas têm de ser retornadas do BD mesmo que somente sua agregação seja necessária).

Comment: @mgibsonbr e o que vc recomenda?

Comment: Se a solução do Orion não funcionou pra você, então infelizmente não tenho nada melhor pra recomendar... Você poderia usar SQL "cru" usando `extra`, mas também não é o ideal (pois reduz-se a portabilidade do código). De todo modo, não estou dizendo que a técnica desta resposta é ruim, estou somente apontando uma característica de performance da mesma - que se torna mais relevante conforme o volume de dados aumente (mas que ainda assim pode ser satisfatória, isso é você quem tem que avaliar conforme o seu caso particular).

Comment: @mgibsonbr OK, obrigado pelos comentários, mas por enquanto já está resolvido com a solução que eu postei acima. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

*Para agrupar por dia, basta apenas agrupar por `date`.

Sendo do tipo `DateField`, basta fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> Subscription.objects.values('created_at').annotate(number=Count('id'))
[{'number': 1, 'created_at': datetime.date(2015, 12, 5)}]
```

Caso o tipo seja `DateTimeField`, eu converti para o tipo `DateField` usando condicionais e funções:

```
>>> from django.db.models import DateField, Case, F
>>> Subscription.objects.annotate(tipo_datefield=Case(default=F('created_at'), output_field=DateField())).values('tipo_datefield').annotate(number=Count('id'))
```

Um outro modo de realizar isso (ainda não está na documentação) é usando `Date` pra extrair o dia:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Date
Subscription.objects.annotate(
    day=Date('created_at', 'day')
).values('day').annotate(number=Count('id'))
```

Comment: É do tipo DatetimeField e está contando um por um, não está agrupando. Eu falei que eu preciso agrupar por dia?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva se o tipo for `datefield` ele agrupará por dia, não precisa extrair o dia do `date`. Adicionei um modo de agrupar por `date` caso seja um `datetime`.

Comment: ele não está agrupando por dia, está retornando number=1 para cada data, mas era pra retornar dia 22, 3; 21, 10 por exemplo.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva aqui está funcionando

Comment: @RegisdaSilva adicionei mais uma solução.

Comment: estranho, nenhuma das soluções funcionou. Ah, veja no meu github https://github.com/rg3915/wttd2/blob/master/eventex/subscriptions/models.py#L11 que o campo é DatetimeField. Estou usando Django 1.9.1

Comment: @RegisdaSilva o problema não está no código, talvez você não tenha cadastrado nada, ou não há cadastros no mesmo dia, o que eu coloquei está tudo correto e funcionando 100%.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva qual erro está aparecendo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34733/discussion-between-regis-da-silva-and-orion).